# Spring: Uncaught Exception in Transactional Method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I'm building a RESTful API and have the following update method in my ProductController:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController implements ProductAPI {

    private final ProductService productService;

    @Override
    public Product updateProduct(Integer id, @Valid UpdateProductDto productDto) throws ProductNotFoundException,
            ProductAlreadyExistsException {

        log.info("Updating product {}", id);
        log.debug("Update Product DTO: {}", productDto);

        Product product = productService.updateProduct(id, productDto);

        log.info("Updated product {}", id);
        log.debug("Updated Product: {}", product);

        return product;
    }

}
```

The throwable exceptions come from the ProductService which has the following implementation:

```
package com.example.ordersapi.product.service.impl;

import com.example.ordersapi.product.api.dto.CreateProductDto;
import com.example.ordersapi.product.api.dto.UpdateProductDto;
import com.example.ordersapi.product.entity.Product;
import com.example.ordersapi.product.exception.ProductAlreadyExistsException;
import com.example.ordersapi.product.exception.ProductNotFoundException;
import com.example.ordersapi.product.mapper.ProductMapper;
import com.example.ordersapi.product.repository.ProductRepository;
import com.example.ordersapi.product.service.ProductService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final ProductMapper productMapper;

    @Override
    public Set<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(productRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public Product getOneProduct(Integer id) throws ProductNotFoundException {
        return productRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ProductNotFoundException(id));
    }

    @Override
    public Product createProduct(CreateProductDto productDto) throws ProductAlreadyExistsException {
        Product product = productMapper.createProductDtoToProduct(productDto);
        Product savedProduct = saveProduct(product);

        return savedProduct;
    }

    private Product saveProduct(Product product) throws ProductAlreadyExistsException {
        try {
            return productRepository.save(product);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            throw new ProductAlreadyExistsException(product.getName());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method needs to be wrapped in a transaction because we are making two database queries:
     *  1. Finding the Product by id (read)
     *  2. Updating found product (write)
     *
     *  Other database clients might perform a write operation over the same entity between our read and write,
     *  which would cause inconsistencies in the system. Thus, we have to operate over a snapshot of the database and
     *  commit or rollback (and probably re-attempt the operation?) depending if its state has changed meanwhile.
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Product updateProduct(Integer id, UpdateProductDto productDto) throws ProductNotFoundException,
            ProductAlreadyExistsException {

        Product foundProduct = getOneProduct(id);
        boolean productWasUpdated = false;

        if (productDto.getName() != null && !productDto.getName().equals(foundProduct.getName())) {
            foundProduct.setName(productDto.getName());
            productWasUpdated = true;
        }

        if (productDto.getDescription() != null && !productDto.getDescription().equals(foundProduct.getDescription())) {
            foundProduct.setDescription(productDto.getDescription());
            productWasUpdated = true;
        }

        if (productDto.getImageUrl() != null && !productDto.getImageUrl().equals(foundProduct.getImageUrl())) {
            foundProduct.setImageUrl(productDto.getImageUrl());
            productWasUpdated = true;
        }

        if (productDto.getPrice() != null && !productDto.getPrice().equals(foundProduct.getPrice())) {
            foundProduct.setPrice(productDto.getPrice());
            productWasUpdated = true;
        }

        Product updateProduct = productWasUpdated ? saveProduct(foundProduct) : foundProduct;

        return updateProduct;
    }

}
```

Because I've set the NAME column as UNIQUE in my database, when an update is issued with an already existing name, the repository save method will throw a `DataIntegrityViolationException`. In the createProduct method it works fine, but in the updateProduct, the call to the private method saveProduct doesn't catch the Exception no matter what and thus the `DataIntegrityViolationException` bubbles to the Controller.

I know it is because I'm wrapping the code in a transaction because removing the @Transactional "solves" the problem. I think it has something to do with the fact that Spring uses a Proxy to wrap the method in a transaction and thus the service call in the controller isn't actually calling the service method (directly). Even though, I don't understand why does it ignore the catch branch to throw the `ProductAlreadyExistsException` when it works fine for the `ProductNotFoundException`.

I know I could also make another trip to the database, try to find a product by name and in case of absence would I try to save my entity back. But that would make everything even more inefficient.

I can also catch the `DataIntegrityViolationException` in the controller layer and throw the `ProductAlreadyExistsException` there but I would be exposing details from the persistence layer there, which doesn't seem appropriate.

Is there a way to handle it all in the service layer, as I'm trying to do now?

P.S.: Outsourcing the logic to a new method and use it internally **seems** to work but only because calls to the **this** won't actually be intercepted by the Transaction Manager proxy and thus no transaction is actually performed

Comment: If the ask is for no rollback on DataIntegrityViolationException , you can use the https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#rollbackFor-- attribute of Transactional annotation. A runtime exception (DataIntegrityVIolationException) thrown within a transaction will mark the transaction for rollback .

Comment: @Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've already tried @Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class) but without success. Maybe it is because the provided implementation for the CrudRepository is also annotated with @Transactional ?

Comment: Are you sure the exception thrown is DataIntegrityViolationException ? Please share the stacktrace

Comment: Yep it was a DataIntegrityViolationException. I even replaced DataIntegrityViolationException in the catch clause for just Exception and it would still not catch it. But Piotr answer ended up solving the problem. Regardless, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work you would need to change `saveProduct` method as follows:

```
        try {
            return productRepository.saveAndFlush(product);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            throw new ProductAlreadyExistsException(product.getName());
        }
```

When you use the `save()` method, the data associated with the save operation will not be flushed to your database unless and until an explicit call to `flush()` or `commit()` method is made. That causes `DataIntegrityViolationException` being thrown later that you would expect and therefore it isn't beeing catched in the snipper above.

`saveAndFlush()` method on the other hand, flushes the data immediately. That should trigger expected exception being catched immidietely and re-throwed as `ProductAlreadyExistsException`.

Comment: Thank you! I've extended JpaRepository instead of CrudRepository, replaced the save method for the saveAndFlush and finally add `@Transactional(rollbackFor = ProductAlreadyExistsException.class)` to the method and it is now working!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. One more thing I wanted to make sure of - `@Transactional(rollbackFor = ProductAlreadyExistsException.class)` will only rollback transaction if `ProductAlreadyExistsException` was thrown or some other exception that extend it. You must be aware that if any other exception (`NullPointerException`, `IllegalStateException`, `IllegalArgumentException` - you name it) is thrown inside this transaction it will be commited regardless. You may be OK with it, just wanted make sure you're aware of that.

Comment: I think that by default, Spring transactions will get rolled back if an unchecked exception is thrown. I'm not sure if I'm overriding that behaviour this way though... I've seen in lots of places that if we want to roll them back on checked exceptions as well we can use `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`. I just decided to be more explicit but you're right, I might be leaving out some margin for error this way... Either way, I needed to specify either `ProductAlreadyExistsException ` or `Exception` for everything to work

Comment: Yes, by default it rollback on `RuntimeException` so you have to override `rollbackFor` argument as `ProductAlreadyExistsException` does not extend `RuntimeException`. The question is whether you want to be specific and rollback ONLY on `ProductAlreadyExistsException` or on any exception. The decistion is yours :)

Comment: Exactly :) I think I would be safer if I was to use `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`

One other thing that kind of surprised me was the fact that I did have to specify `ProductAlreadyExistsException` in the rollback options but I never had to specify `ProductNotFoundException`, even though they are on the same level... I tried to find an explanation but cannot fathom what might be happening there