# Transaction marked as rollback-only with unknown reason

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have some code like below.

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service
{
    @Transactional
    public myObject methodOne()
    {
        if (myCondition)
          return methodTwo();
        else 
          anotherMethod();
    }

    public myObject methodTwo()
    {
        int retryCount = 1;
        myObject myObject = null;
        while (retryCount <= 10) {
            try {
                myObject = repository.save();
                break;
            } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ignored) {
                retryCount++;
            }
        }
        if (myObject == null){
            throw new MyException();
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws exception

> Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as
>   rollback-only

even i catched in `methodTwo()` and `myObject != null`. Can anyone help me please!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be due to rollback rules in subtransactions.

How about `methodTwo` return `myObject` and check at `methodOne`

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service
{
    @Transactional
    public myObject methodOne()
    {
        myObject myObject = methodTwo()'
        if (myObject == null){
            throw new MyException();
        }

        return myObject;
    }

    public myObject methodTwo()
    {
        int retryCount = 1;
        myObject myObject = null;
        while (retryCount <= 10) {
            try {
                myObject = repository.save();
                break;
            } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ignored) {
                retryCount++;
            }
        }
        return myObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any `RuntimeException` within the transaction , *that Spring becomes aware of* , will mark that transaction for rollback.

Considering the transaction propagation for `repository.save()` is [REQUIRED](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED) and the call to `repository.save()` resulted in a `DataIntegrityViolationException` which is a subclass for `RuntimeException`, the transaction will get marked for rollback even though it is handled/caught at `methodTwo()`.

[noRollbackFor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#noRollbackFor--)/[noRollbackForClassName](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#rollbackForClassName--) attributes of [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation can be used to control the rollback behaviour. example ,

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
```

Note : *RuntimeExceptions that Spring becomes aware of*  is that , if a `RuntimeException` is thrown explicitly and handled within the same method , Spring will not be aware of that exception and will not mark the surrounding transaction for rollback . The `RuntimeException` should propagate through the spring proxies for this to happen , which happened with your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i just add @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(noRollbackFor = {DataIntegrityViolationException.class}) but still throws above exception

Comment: Could you please update the complete stack trace to the question. The exception will be thrown , but no rollback happens on that exception is what we tell with that annotation attribute.I assume the exception thrown will be different one.Also could you please check if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59534124/4214241) helps you out .